# AutoHotKey: Horizontal scrolling in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, scrollbar, monodevelop, autohotkey

I'd like to bind horizontal scrolling to shift+wheelup/down using AutoHotKey, so I've tried the scripts suggested in [this topic](https://superuser.com/questions/13763/horizontal-scrolling-shortcut-in-windows) but none of them worked.

(one of this scripts also had a nice feature "scoll what's below the mouse, instead of the active window": this worked)

I guess either the problem lies with Windows 8 or with MonoDevelop (I've read it worked for *most* programs but not all of them).

Is anyone aware of a solution that would allow me to do that?

Comment: Any programs in particular that you couldn't get to work? A few of these methods worked for most programs for me.

Comment: @ElliotDeNolf MonoDevelop. I also couldn't get it to work with SourceTree but I don't care. Maybe it works with some other programs but I didn't even try (since what I need it for is MonoDevelop, and as long as it doesn't work there, I don't need it otherwhere).